# Custom URL is not being correctly generated in privacy settings

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

When setting my privacy settings I've note that the URL of my profile had "http" and "https" at same time. See below.

[image]

Comment: @Jason wrong tag. Removed it, but can't put [tag:status-reproduced] myself. (Missing diamond ;))

Comment: Bug confirmed. It's on the tracker and will be fixed, eventually. UPDATE - See my answer below.

Comment: @Juice should I use MSO from now on for Careers questions, and instruct others to do so? It used to be MSE for long years.

Comment: Declined? You refuse to fix such  a bug??? OK. I'm backing off.

Comment: It's gonna be fixed, just gonna take a month or so.

Comment: @Shog9 "we're declining bugs on careers.stackoverflow unless their a huge dealbreaker". So is this deemed a huge dealbreaker?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the bug only occurs on careers.stackoverflow and not on the integrated jobs tab on Stack Overflow. Soon(ish), 4-6 weeks, etc; we'll be turning off careers.stackoverflow for users and solely use the jobs tab. So unless things change, we're declining bugs on careers.stackoverflow unless the are a huge dealbreaker.

Comment: So, 4-6 weeks is soon(ish), 6-8 weeks is standard? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Basically 100% of what see and do on Careers will be replicated on the Jobs tab on Stack Overflow. Careers.stackoverflow will eventually be turned into an employer-only portal.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The income stream isn't changing, just the channel you tune to.

Comment: @
ShadowWizard
The team is going to email developers who are Careers users announcing that Jobs on Stack Overflow will be their new home...just haven't done it yet while they're getting the house in order. :)

Comment: I hope one's profile will be ported automatically to the Jobs tab